# How to wrap html text into spans with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to wrap a text from html in a span so it should be like this

```
<p>Test yes</p>
```

into

```
<p><span>Test</span></p>
```

with `javascript` dom. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test_para">Test yes</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var p = document.getElementById('test_para')

        var span = document.createElement('span');
        var node = document.createTextNode(p.innerHTML);
        span.appendChild(node);

        p.innerHTML  = '';
        p.appendChild(span);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the snippet we did following things:

1. First we assigned id `test_para` to our paragraph. Through this id we locate it and store in variable p.
2. Second we create span element using `createElement()` method.
3. Third we create a text node using `createTextNode()` method and store text of our paragraph inside it.
4. Next we set add this node to span element we just created using `appendChild()` method.
5. Finally we make our paragraph empty and append newly created span element to it using `appendChild()` method.

There is another more less sophisticated way to do this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test_para">Test yes</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var p = document.getElementById('test_para')
        p.innerHTML  = '<span>'+p.innerHTML+'</spn>';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here we locating our paragraph using id as we did in the snippet above. But rather than creating HTML elements using JavaScript, we just changing the HTML inside of our paragraph using its innerHTML property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML + '</span>';
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(element => {
    element.innerHTML = '<span>' + element.innerHTML + '</span>';
});
```

```html
<p>Test1</p>
<p>Test2</p>
<p>Test3</p>
<p>Test4</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not just text, in case you have some other html entities as well, inside the element like `p` tag here, here is what you can do :

```
var parent = document.querySelector("p");
parent.innerHTML = "<span>" + parent.innerHTML + "</span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

**This, one line would do!**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(e => e.innerHTML = `<span>${e.innerHTML}</span>`)
```